# What is the maximum number of parameters that a method in Swift can have and why?

Tags: swift, llvm

I am interest in the maximum amount of the parameters that could be set in the Swift method and how it is limited ? I read information about how it is done in Java an C# and would like to know how it is done in Swift too.

Comment: Swift is open source so if you're that deeply interested you can study the source...

Comment: I'm not sure there is a correct answer, as it may be (for iOS anyways) memory constrained. By default, Swift parameters a passed by value and read-only, but you can also use *inout* which while not *exactly* a "by reference" (it still copies things in memory), it radically changes an answer to your question. Finally, what do you consider arrays, types, and tuples? So I guess I'd say you need to further define your question before one can give an accurate answer....

Comment: @matt I know it but I asking this because probably someone investigate this and can share their experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you believe there's an arbitrary limit on the number of parameters? The Swift language reference defines no particular limit. If you look at the [grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/parameter-clause), the parameter clause is defined recursively as:

```
parameter-clause → (­)­ | (­parameter-list­)­
parameter-list → parameter­ | parameter­,­parameter-list
```

It's possible that there's some compiler implementation detail that restricts this to a finite length (before memory is exhausted, which of course would limit it in practice), but I'm not aware of one and it's unclear why one would be expected. You certainly couldn't rely on it.

Looking at the [AST](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/include/swift/AST/ParameterList.h), I don't see any evidence of an arbitrary limit at that level. It looks, as you would expect, to be a dynamically allocated list.